# WordPress - Custom page order for next_post_link within custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

next_post_link as far as I'm aware, just gets the next post within the taxonomy based on date of creation. I was wondering if I could use custom fields to have it select the next post by the order in there. Like a page number field and it grabs the next post within the taxonomy with the next page number.

So we're in Taxonomy 'x' on page 2 (created 2 weeks ago), and want to move to page 3 (created today), and there's a page 4 (created 1 week ago).

It would go to page 4, but I want it to go to page 3.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom fields like you mentioned, it wouldn't be using a taxonomy. You would be ordering the posts, or getting the posts, based on the `get_field()` function for acf.

```
$posts = get_posts();
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    // This gets the custom field from ACF
    $post->order = get_field('name-of-field', $post->ID);
    if ($post->order == whatever_number_you_want) {
        $active_post = $post;
    }
}

echo $active_post;
```